Resize the image to avoid overflow
I am trying to get this image in my window. But the image is of a large size. I want the size of the image to shrink if the window size decreases and expand if it increases. with the present code the increasing part works well. But instead of decreasing it throws a render overflow error.
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Default extends StatefulWidget {
  const Default({super.key});

  @override
  State<Default> createState() => _DefaultState();
}

class _DefaultState extends State<Default> {
  Map articles = {};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ColorScheme colors = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 2,
              child: ColorFiltered(
                  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                        colors.background, BlendMode.darken),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              "assets/images/shelf.png"),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              "assets/images/shelf.png"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )],
                  ),
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
        ],),
        );
  }
}


IMAGE:

I have tried fitted box, boxfits but none work.

Try using Flexible, if still overflow share the image you want to create.

Try to replace body with given code... hope it helps
body: ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(colors.background, BlendMode.darken),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/a.jpg"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/b.jpg"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/a.jpg"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/b.jpg"),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
        ],
      ),

If you want to scroll vertically use below code
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ColorFiltered(
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(colors.background, BlendMode.darken),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/a.jpg"),
                      Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/b.jpg"),
                      Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/a.jpg"),
                      Image.asset(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/b.jpg"),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "hello"),
        ],
      ),


Thanks for answering but the given code makes the application hang right away such that it never revives and has to be rebuilded which again gives the same output.
